# A definite integral­

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_{-\frac\pi2}^{\frac\pi2}\frac{\ln(1+b\sin x)}{\sin x} dx \\|b|<1$$

I tried putting $-x$ using properties of definite integral, but that doesn't really help.

$$I=\int_{-\frac\pi2}^{\frac\pi2}\frac{-\ln(1-b\sin x)}{\sin x}dx$$

I don't think adding these 2 equations would yield anything. And I just cannot think of a good substitution.

**Edit :** Plugging b=1, it gives 4.9xxx . as $\pi ^2 \approx 10$, the value is $\pi \arcsin b$. Other values for b confirm this.

Comment: Maybe integration by parts?

Comment: @orion I think that it will complicate it further.

Comment: Even wolfram alpha isn't replying...

Comment: $$I(b)=\int_{-\frac\pi2}^{\frac\pi2}\frac{\ln(1+b\sin x)}{\sin x}dx\iff I'(b)=\int_{-\frac\pi2}^{\frac\pi2}\frac{dx}{1+b\sin x}$$

Comment: I tried this but the [new integral](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2F%281%2Bbsin%28x%29%29+dx) in b looked scary.

Comment: Definitely. May be properties would have simplified it.

Comment: @awesome. look at what wolfram alpha [says](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+ln%281%2B0.5sin%28x%29%29%2Fsin%28x%29) for the case when b = 0.5. I think that it is not possible to integrate this function without those limits.

Comment: Lets hope someone finds a better solution.

Comment: Hope is a good thing, maybe the best of things.

Comment: @Lucian. Thanks a lot for such a clever idea. Cheers.

Comment: @LakshayGarg. The new integral is quite simple and definitly useful. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been trying to compute the antiderivative; I tried several change of variable with absolutely nos success; as already mentioned, integration by parts makes the problem still more complex.

Using a CAS (brut force), the antiderivative which came out is just a nightmare for me $$-\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{\tan
   \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{b^2-1}-b}\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{\tan
   \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{b+\sqrt{b^2-1}}\right)+\log \left(\tan
   \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right) \left(-\log \left(\frac{\tan
   \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{b^2-1}+b}+1\right)-\log
   \left(\left(\sqrt{b^2-1}+b\right) \tan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+1\right)+\log (b
   \sin (x)+1)+\log \left(1-i \tan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)+\log \left(1+i
   \tan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)\right)+\frac{1}{2} \text{Li}_2\left(-\tan
   ^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)$$  Computing the integral leads, after simplifications, to $$-\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{b^2-1}-b}\right)-\frac{1}{2} \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{\left(b+\sqrt{b^2-1}\right)^2}\right)+2
   \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{b+\sqrt{b^2-1}}\right)+\text{Li}_2\left(b+\sqrt{b^2-1}\right) $$ which is a real valued function of $b$. Trying to use the definition and properties of the dilogarithm took me to a dead end.

Thanks to your edit and clever remark, I verified that the result is exactly what you said, that is to say that $$\int_{-\frac\pi2}^{\frac\pi2}\frac{\ln(1+b\sin x)}{\sin x} dx = \pi \sin ^{-1}(b)$$

I checked that the Taylor series built at $b=0$ are identical.

Congratulations for having found the result. I am really sorry to have not been able to simplify these monsters.

**Added later after Lucian's suggestion**

After Lucian's so good suggestion, let us consider $$I'(b)=\int_{-\frac\pi2}^{\frac\pi2}\frac{dx}{1+b\sin x}$$ First of all, the antiderivative is given by $$\frac{2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{b+\tan
   \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{1-b^2}}\right)}{\sqrt{1-b^2}}$$ Integrated between the given bounds $$I'(b)=\frac{2 \left(\tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-b}{1+b}}\right)+\tan
   ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1+b}{1-b}}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{1-b^2}}=\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{1-b^2}}$$   and the final result for $I(b)$.

Comment: This should be not be that tough...

Comment: @Awesome. I agree with you. Fortunately, you receive a nice answer from Lakshay Garg.

Comment: @Claude. And my search for a better solution comes to an end. Well done.

Answer (score 14):

From the Taylor series expansion of $\ln(1+x)$ we know that
$$\ln(1+b\sin x) = b\sin x - \frac{b^2\sin^2x}{2} +\frac{b^3\sin^3x}{3} - \cdots$$

Therefore
$$\frac{\ln(1+b\sin x)}{\sin x} = b - \frac{b^2\sin x }{2} +\frac{b^3\sin^2 x }{3}-\cdots$$

Integrating both sides of the equation
$$\int^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2}\frac{\ln(1+b\sin x )}{\sin x }\mathrm{d}x = \int^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2} b - \frac{b^2\sin x }{2} +\frac{b^3\sin^2 x }{3}-\cdots \mathrm{d}x$$

Observe that $\int^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2}\sin^nx\mathrm{d}x = 0$ if n is an odd number. The above equation is then equivalent to
$$\int^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2}\frac{\ln(1+b\sin x )}{\sin x }\mathrm{d}x = \int^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2} b  +\frac{b^3\sin^2 x }{3}+\frac{b^5\sin^4 x }{5}\cdots \mathrm{d}x$$

As $\sin^{2n}x$ is an even function therefore
$$\int^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2}\frac{\ln(1+b\sin x )}{\sin x }\mathrm{d}x =2 \int^{\pi/2}_0 b  +\frac{b^3\sin^2 x }{3}+\frac{b^5\sin^4 x }{5}\cdots \mathrm{d}x$$

Using the fact that $\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^nx\mathrm{d}x = \frac{(n-1)\cdot(n-3)\cdots3\cdot1}{n\cdot(n-2)\cdots4\cdot2}$ if n is even (See this [page](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110309100121AAKoHR3) for the proof)

$$\int^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2}\frac{\ln(1+b\sin x )}{\sin x }\mathrm{d}x =2\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}\Bigg[ b+\frac{b^3}{3}\frac{1}{2}+\frac{b^5}{5}\frac{3\cdot1}{4\cdot2}\cdots\Bigg]$$
$$=\pi\Bigg[ b+\frac{b^3}{3}\frac{1}{2}+\frac{b^5}{5}\frac{3\cdot1}{4\cdot2}\cdots\Bigg]$$
The term in the parenthesis is precisely the Taylor series expansion (Thanks to your edit. I was completely clueless at this point) for $\sin^{-1} b $. Therefore the integral is 
$$\int^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2}\frac{\ln(1+b\sin x )}{\sin x }\mathrm{d}x = \pi\sin^{-1} b $$

Comment: Knowing the answer this looks like back working.

Comment: Actually it in not. I checked it only after your edit that it was indeed the expansion for arcsin(b). Anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: @awesome. I am curious to see if you get a better answer.

Comment: We have to see how the hell someone made this question?

Comment: @LakshayGarg. Thanks for this answer. I also started using Taylor expansions but they were based on $x$ and not $\sin(x)$ (you can see how stupid I can be or I am). Cheers.

Comment: You have certainly made an excellent effort...But See Lucian's comment above... This was simpler. How could we have forgot that?

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\mbox{Let's}\ {\cal I}\pars{b} \equiv
    \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}{\ln\pars{1 + b\sin\pars{x}} \over \sin\pars{x}}
     \,\dd x:\ {\large ?}}$ with $\ds{b \in {\mathbb R}\,,\ \verts{b} < 1.\quad}$
$\ds{{\cal I}\pars{0} = 0}$

> With
>   [Weierstrass Substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) $\ds{t \equiv \tan\pars{x \over 2}}$:
>   \begin{align}
> {\cal I}'\pars{b}&=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}{\dd x \over 1 + b\sin\pars{x}}
> =\int_{-1}^{1}{2\,\dd t/\pars{1 + t^{2}} \over 1 + b\bracks{2t/\pars{1 + t^{2}}}}
> =2\int_{-1}^{1}{\dd t \over t^{2} + 2bt + 1}
> \\[3mm]&=2\int_{-1}^{1}{\dd t \over \pars{t + b}^{2} + 1 - b^{2}}
> =2\int_{-1 + b}^{1 + b}{\dd t \over t^{2} + 1 - b^{2}}
> \\[3mm]&={2 \over \root{1 - b^{2}}}
> \int_{\pars{-1 + b}/\root{1 - b^{2}}}^{\pars{1 + b}/\root{1 - b^{2}}}
> {\dd t \over t^{2} + 1}
> \\[3mm]&={2 \over \root{1 - b^{2}}}\bracks{%
> \arctan\pars{1 + b \over \root{1 - b^{2}}}
> -\arctan\pars{-1 + b \over \root{1 - b^{2}}}}
> \\[3mm]&={2 \over \root{1 - b^{2}}}\bracks{%
> {\pi \over 2} - \arctan\pars{\root{1 - b^{2}} \over 1 + b}
> -\arctan\pars{-1 + b \over \root{1 - b^{2}}}}
> \\[3mm]&={2 \over \root{1 - b^{2}}}\braces{%
> {\pi \over 2} - \overbrace{%
> \bracks{\arctan\pars{1 - b \over \root{1 - b^{2}}}
> +\arctan\pars{-1 + b \over \root{1 - b^{2}}}}}^{\ds{=\ 0}}}
> \\[3mm]&={\pi \over \root{1 -b^{2}}}
> \end{align}

Then
$$\color{#00f}{\large%
\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}{\ln\pars{1 + b\sin\pars{x}} \over \sin\pars{x}}\,\dd x
=\pi\,\arcsin\pars{b}}
$$